# Preventing JS Class Methods From Running Until Variables Are Set

Tags: javascript, oop, d3.js, svg

I'm working with OO JavaScript and I'm trying to implement an interface for my class like `D3`.

```
var object = ObjectType
   .property1(value)
   .property2(value)
```

My class builds 2 SVG arcs (one for the background and one for the value), but because of the way I've set things up, it's being built before its values are initialized. I really would like to build with the pattern I've described above, but I can't find the right resource.

```
var tempArc = new AnnularSection(-90, 90, 120, 140);
   .valueColor = "#77933c";


function AnnularSection(startAngle, endAngle, moveRight, moveDown) {
    this.startAngle = startAngle * Math.PI/180;
    this.endAngle    = endAngle * Math.PI/180;
    this.moveRight  = moveRight;
    this.moveDown   = moveDown;
    this.valueColor;

    this.section = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(93)
        .outerRadius(118)
        .startAngle(this.startAngle)
        .endAngle(this.endAngle);

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("d", this.section)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + moveRight + "," + moveDown + ")");

    this.valueArc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(93)
        .outerRadius(118)
        .startAngle(this.startAngle)
        .endAngle(this.endAngle);

    this.value = svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", this.valueColor)
        .attr("d", this.valueArc)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + moveRight + "," + moveDown + ")");

    this.updateValue = function (newEnd) {

        console.log(this);

        this.valueArc.transition().duration(750).call(arcTween, newEnd);

        function arcTween(transition, newEnd) {
            transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {
                var interpolateEnd = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, endAngle);
                return function(t) {
                    d.endAngle = interpolateEnd(t);
                    return arc(d);
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to follow the pattern [described here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)?

Comment: This looks great. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, cool. Then the main 2 differences between what you have and what's described in that article is that 1) `updateValue()` should become a pure getter+setter that doesn't run any rendering code, and 2) `AnnularSection` needs to become an idempotent render function, meaning that it should be possible to call it multiple times and always get the correct rendering (so `append` the way you have does not satisfy this requirement). Also, it's best to avoid relying on the `this` keyword.